# Change Label text from different class in java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a main gui class which has been made in the NetBeans gui builder. I am creating a mini game where the JLabel timer goes down. The JLabel is located in the main gui and the timer is located in a separate classes called `timer` for instance. When the loop for the timer is looping, I want the JLabel located in the main gui to change (Timer=10, Timer=9, ...etc).

Review the sample code below for a better understanding.

This is the class where the timer is located:

```
public class ShapeGame {

Timer timer;
int counter = 10;

ShapeGame() {

    ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Counter = " + counter);
            labTimer.setText("Timer: " + counter);
            if (--counter < 0) {
                timer.stop();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer(1000, a);
    timer.start();
    }
}
```

This is amended code for where the JLabel is located:

(NOTE: not all code has been added for the JLabel and JFrame just for reading purposes)

```
public class mainGui extends JFrame {

labTimer = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    private void gameStartStopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        ShapeGame sg = new ShapeGame();
    }
}
```

I understand this is not the correct way to call the Label from a different class `labTimer.setText("Timer: " + counter);`. Hope I have provided enough information to help solve this problem.

Comment: Either pass a reference of the label to the ActionListner (not the best solution) or set up an observer pattern with the ActionLisyener, so it can notify interested parties when it changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible simple (but not clean) solution is to pass the JLabel into the ShapeGame class so that it can mutate its state directly.

e.g.,

```
public class ShapeGame {
    Timer timer;
    int counter = 10;

    // note change to constructor parameter
    public ShapeGame(final JLabel label) {
        ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Counter = " + counter);

                // note changes
                // labTimer.setText("Timer: " + counter);
                label.setText("Timer: " + counter);

                if (--counter < 0) {
                    timer.stop();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer(1000, a);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Then when creating the ShapeGame class, pass the JLabel into its constructor call. Cleaner would be to structure your program a la MVC.